# change padding, margin, and font size in jquery mobile footer navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation

I'm trying to adjust the padding and/or margin and/or font size in some buttons that I have in my jquery mobile footer to create some more real estate.

currently, the buttons appear to have some padding inside them that I could squeeze in tighter and it would give me some more room to include some more text within them.

here is what I"m using to create my nav:

```
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="/home/howworks" data-transition="fade" data-theme="a" data-icon="">
                How This Works
            </a>
            <a href="/home/privacypolicy" data-transition="fade" data-theme="a" data-icon="">
                Privacy
            </a>
            <a href="/home/termsandconditions" data-transition="fade" data-theme="a" data-icon="">
                Conditions
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd love to be able to just throw in a style or two and create some more room if at all possible.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but this may be it:

```
.ui-footer .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 1px !important;
}

.ui-footer .ui-btn-text {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Try it out on JS-fiddle if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/g6QH5/

​

Comment: yup...this got me there.  Thanks much!